# Autocomplete not working for JavaScript

Tags: spacemacs, auto-complete-mode, js2-mode

So I can't get Auto-Complete to work for JavaScript. I've tried a variety of solutions but nothing seems to be working. Here is the relevant code snippet:

```el
;;
;;adds js2-mode for javascript autocompletion
;;
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs-config/js2-mode")
(require 'js2-mode)
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.js\\'" . js2-mode))

;;
;;adds auto complete
;;
;Load the default configuration
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs-config/auto-complete")
(require 'auto-complete-config)
; Make sure we can find the dictionaries
(add-to-list 'ac-dictionary-directories "~/.emacs-config/auto-complete/dict")
; Use dictionaries by default
(ac-config-default)
(dolist (m '(js2-mode))
  (add-to-list 'ac-modes m))
;Start auto-completion after 2 characters of a word
(setq ac-auto-start 2)
; case sensitivity is important when finding matches
(setq ac-ignore-case nil)
```

Also, I install and manage all of my packages manually with Git, and I am on Emacs 24.5.1 and running spacemacs. Anyone have any insight into this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You still need an auto-complete source, do you not?

You could try [ac-js2](https://github.com/ScottyB/ac-js2). Please note that I have not tried this.

Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26812853/js2-auto-complete-not-working-on-emacs)